# Expected value for full Poisson Process is known; can I know the EV half process?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have 100 computers on a network.

Using the Poisson Process, the network is expected to generate a message 6 times a minute.

With this information, if I were to take 50 computers off of the network, can I say the new Expected Value is 3 messages per minute?

Comment: Yes, if the messages originate from individual computers and message generation is independent of the other computers.

Comment: @LutzL Thanks, if you make it an answer I can accept it. Also it would be great if you could link to a sorce with more info. I couldnt find any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the computers act all independently with the according to identical Poisson processes, then the average waiting time until the next event for each computer is $1000s$, so the combined waiting time for $100$ computers is $10s$. By the same reasoning the combined waiting time for $50$ computers is $20s$ or 3 events per minute.